# Substring regex match

Tags: php, regex, string, substring

I'd like a regex to match the substring "Type I" and NOT "Type II"

Using PHP

The following works for a single case, but I'm running it in a loop and not all cases end with a word boundary

```
preg_match('/Type I\b/', $string)
```

Data set with desired outcome:

```
Type I #pass
Type I, #pass
, Type I, #pass
Type II #fail
Type II, #fail
, Type II, #fail
```

Comment: I don't understand your question, what is your input and your expected output?

Comment: what is the dataset?

Comment: But your pattern `/Type I\b/`  works correct. doesn't it? https://regex101.com/r/hF0wP2/1 matched "Type I" and NOT "Type II"...

Comment: Show your example strings where "Type I" isn't followed by a word-boundary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://regex101.com/r/fH9yV2/1

```
$re = "/Type I(?!I)/";
```

This takes your `Type I`, and asserts that the next character is not another `I`.

For more about lookaround assertions: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

It appears that you are just beginning to understand regex. I suggest you look around the above website more, as it is a great tool for learning regex.

Comment: The lookarounds were what I needed